# Scaled preview: use NSTextView, NSTextField, CATextLayer, or drawInRect?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview, catextlayer

I'm programming a cocoa app that presents text (vertically and horizontally) centered on a projector screen.

I'd like to have a small preview of what I see on the "wall" in a cocoa window on the computer's screen (in a `NSCollectionView`). Just like "presenter mode" in Powerpoint where you see the current and the next slide as previews.

Which way do you recommend for implementing the presented text?

`NSTextField` turned out to be tricky for aligning and scaling the text. `CATextLayer`, on the other hand, feels a little bit overkill for such a simple task, even though the scaling works like a charm. Would using `NSTextView` or `drawInRect` be a good trade-off?

I appreciate your assistance in making sure that I didn't miss something out before I spend hours and days on this :) My goals are to keep it robust and simple. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend `CATextLayer`. If the user need to edit the text in the collection view, then you could pop up a `NSTextField`.

Answer (score 1):

`CATextLayer` is definitely not overkill. In fact, a `CATextLayer` is considerably more lightweight than an `NSView` and would seem ideal for your situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your estimation. You were absolutely right. It works great.